# A generalization of relative interior?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

In an infinite-dimension space, the relative interior of a non-empty convex set may be empty. I was wondering whether there is a concept (as a generalization of relative interior) with the following properties: for any non-empty convex set,

1. Its "concept" is non-empty.
2. Whenever the relative interior of this set is non-empty, its "concept" is the same as the relative interior.